# When to use "We" versus "I" in a professional email?

Tags: word-usage, business-language

I'm trying to explain to a coworker when I use "We" versus "I" in my work emails going outside of the organization, but I don't know myself.

For example,

> Hello,
>
> This morning **we** were unable to connect the recovery channel at 142.201.223.154:11199. **Our** keys are current and have not been modified. Could you check for connectivity issues on your end? **We'd** appreciate it very much.
>
> Thank you.

But then, after getting a response,

> **I** see, thank you. It was indeed an old server **we** were trying to revive.
>
> **I** see a range of new recovery addresses in an email from last year, but none match the user and feed addresses for this server.
>
> [...]

Not the greatest example, but I've thought about this distinction before too, and I remember noticing myself using "I" more when I'm at fault, or possibly at fault, or admitting something. As an investigation continues, if the correspondent asks more details, I reply using "we," except when I'm not sure my thoughts are correct, in which case I use "I." Why is that?

English is my first language, and I don't think I'm alone in switching up these pronouns this way. But what is the logical pattern behind it? And more practically, how can I explain it to a non-native speaker of English?

Comment: To clarify, in those email example, it was just _me_ who was "unable to connect the recovery channel," and trying to revive the old server.

Comment: It seems it's as simple as accuracy, as in whether or not you are directly representing a group of people.  None of you have connection in the first case, but in the second their email wasn't passed around to everyone for everyone to troubleshoot; a single individual did so ("I").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Whenever you want to portray a holistic action or thought of the group/team/organization then use **We**.

Example-

```
a.**We as a company always believe in serving our customers from the heart**.
```

2.Whenever you want to show your own individual effort/thought/action use **I**.

Example-

b.**I am working on the issue and will keep you updated regarding any progress.**

c.**I really appreciate all the hard work put into this project by every individual involved.**

3.Also, whenever you are interacting with any client then try to transmit team beliefs instead of individual belief.This gives a positive outlook towards the work culture and the image of the company as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

We is (by default) used when the work being done is not a single person's effort, rather an undertaking by an entire community or group.

> **we** were unable to connect

Connection isn't one man's problem.

> **Our** keys are current

Keys used are the same for everyone in the group.

> **We**'d appreciate

If problem is solved, everyone will appreciate

> old server **we** were trying

A large part of the group was trying to revive the server

Whereas 'I' is generally used when one person can represent the whole community. Like

> **I** see, thank you

It means, one person has understood, and will (if required) spread the information to the entire community.(One representing the entire group)

> **I** see a range of new recovery addresses

Checking recovery addresses is generally assigned to a particular person, he checks it on behalf of the entire group. Everyone does not check recovery addresses.